# Dynamic collapse afer Ajax POST

Tags: ajax

Good morning,

I load ajax content into a DIV, but it is impossible to use the collapse initially planned in the code.

Here is a piece of my POST:

```
...
success: function(response)
{
if (response.trim()!='') document.getElementById("youpi_result").innerHTML = response;
youpi_refresh_title_timer = setTimeout(youpi_refresh_title, 5000);
}
...
```

Here is the content that passes through ajax:

```
<ul class="qt-collapsible proradio-chart-tracklist proradio-chart-normal" data-collapsible="accordion">

<?php foreach ($PlayList as $PlayItem) {if ($PlayItem->ID>0) {$PlayItem->Title->Refresh_Data(REFRESH_DATA_IF_NEEDED); ?>
<li id="chartItem-<?php echo esc_attr($pos); ?>" aria-label="Song" class="qt-collapsible-item proradio-paper proradio-part-chart proradio-chart-track proradio- card">
<div id="chartCollapse-<?php echo esc_attr($pos); ?>" class="proradio-chart-table collapsible-header qt-content-primary">
<div class="proradio-position qt-content-primary-dark">
<img src="<?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->Cover_URL()); ?>" class="proradio-chart-cover" alt="Chart track" width="100" height="100 ">
<p class="proradio-capfont"><?php echo substr(date('d-m-Y @ H:i ', convert_timestamp($PlayItem->Date)), -6); ?></p>
</div>
<div class="proradio-titles">
<h4 class="proradio-cutme-t"><?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->Name); ?></h4>
<p class="proradio-itemmetas"><?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->Artist->Name); ?></p>
</div>
<div class="proradio-action">
<?php if ( $PlayItem->Title->URL !== null) echo '<a href="'.html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->URL).'" aria-label="Buy song" class ="proradio-btns qt-content-primary noembed" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></a>'; ?>
</div>
</div>
<div id="chartPlayer-<?php echo esc_attr($pos); ?>" class="collapsible-body proradio-paper">
<div class="qtmplayer-playlist-large">
<ul class="qtmplayer-playlist">
<li class="qtmplayer-trackitem qtmplayer-track-inpage">
<span data-qtmplayer-file="<?php echo html_real_escape_string($Preview_URL); ?>"
data-qtmplayer-cover="<?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->Cover_URL()); ?>"
data-qtmplayer-title="<?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->Name); ?>"
data-qtmplayer-artist="<?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->Artist->Name); ?>"
data-qtmplayer-album="EXCERPT"
data-qtmplayer-link="<?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->URL); ?>"
data-qtmplayer-buylink="test"
data-qtmplayer-type="track" class="qtmplayer-play qtmplayer-link-sec qtmplayer-play-btn"><i class="material-icons" aria-label="Play">play_arrow</i>< /span>
<p>
<span class="qtmplayer-tit"><?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->Name); ?></span>
<span class="qtmplayer-art"><?php echo html_real_escape_string($PlayItem->Title->Artist->Name); ?></span>
</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<?php
$pos = $pos+1;
?>
<?php }} ?>
</ul>
<!-- CHART TRACKLIST END -->
```

I thought that by adding a line after the innerHTML = response; This might work, but I can't find it.

Do you have an idea?

THANKS

Can't find how to make content passed in Ajax dynamic...